# Opinion-Based Closure Vote

Tags: discussion

There is a post that has been selected for Close Vote, based on the fact that it is "primarily opinion-based".

The question in hand is "how to do multisite in Sitecore" which does indeed have a definite answer (config files) as well associated answers like modules, SxA, etc.

But it's a good debate question too. The question I'm curious about though is that, with Sitecore (and .NET in general), there can be several ways to achieve the same goal, and sometimes no concrete direct right way.  But I think those questions should still be asked, and not closed because of opinion-based.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I think if the question is "How to do X" it becomes very broad and debatable about the implementation.

What I meant is "how to do multisite in Sitecore" is broad and opinion-based question since this can be achieved in various ways and depends on needs of the time. What is the core issue that user faced here or what effort was given is not clear in this.

IMHO [One liner question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/81/172) are not good quality post.

Also I would highlight the answer taken from [meta-SO answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255471/468718)

> Ok, so let's try to walk through why this is not so good of an idea.
>
> Let's start with a very old opinion-based question, What
>   non-programming books should programmers read?
>
> Look how many answers there are. 316 of them! That's a lot. That's a
>   lot even if you wanted to read all the posts. The problem is, none of
>   these are wrong, but none of these are right. These are all people's
>   opinions, and you can't tell someone that their opinion is wrong
>   (except for me, I can say whatever I want). So what can we call "the
>   answer". Which one should the OP choose?
>
> Now, that is a more extreme example. Let's take something more recent.
>   How about this recent question. The question boils down to about the
>   same example question you had: "I have this code base, which has these
>   vague requirements, and I need to do a task. What is the best way to
>   approach the problem?"
>
> As of this writing, it has 1 vote for "too broad" and 2 votes for
>   "primarily opinion based". It's "too broad" because there are too many
>   possible methods to attack the problem, and it's "primarily opinion
>   based" because those solutions would be based on the person's opinion.
>   Yes, maybe in a better question which had the specifications better
>   defined you would have a narrower set of results, but really, in the
>   end, most of these questions get opinionated answers. We close these
>   questions to stop people from giving opinionated answers.
>
> A bad question is ok; a bad answer is BAD. That really kills the site.
>
> Another problem with these types of questions is that it's an excuse
>   for the author to be lazy. The tool-tip for downvoting includes "does
>   not show any research effort", and you will be hard-pressed to find a
>   question like this actually showing any sort of research effort. You
>   are wanting us to look up either a method or tool for you to use,
>   instead of making the start yourself.
>
> I always tell people to go to Google first. Say you want to find the
>   best way to move data between your phone app and your desktop app.
>   Well, do you know at least one method? Find one, look it up, research
>   it, figure out if it will work for you or not. Then lookup another,
>   and maybe a third. We want you to help yourself. Only you can find the
>   best tool for your job, and spending the extra time researching
>   yourself will save you, and us, a lot of time.
>
> So your argument to that will be "well we could have one central
>   location for these types of requests, saving internet readers a lot of
>   time in research themselves". True, but this brings us back to the
>   first example in my post: too many "answers", and none of them can be
>   seen as correct or incorrect.
>
> Bottom line: if we allowed opinionated questions, we would be flooded
>   with opinionated answers, and voting would be nothing more than a
>   straw-poll of "which do you like the most". A site reader would have
>   to parse through so much more content to find what they were looking
>   for, which is the ANSWER to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think there have to be nuances. I have a question marked on hold for the same reason, asking about multiple vendor development architecture and processes. That's clearly something that's worth discussing, but there are no right answers. There are (possibly) best practices, there are challenges to be overcome, there are advantages and drawbacks to different solutions. If these are presented in an answer then the question has lead to good, useful, information that may help others. It would be a shame if we closed this down as an avenue, but I'm having difficulty seeing how to reword my question to make it more concrete.